# US H1B visa dropbox | Can I change the petitioner details after visa appointment confirmed and fee paid

Tags: working-visas, h1-visa

I have scheduled an H1B and H4 visa dropbox appointment with my old petitioner (old Employer). Now I have a new job with a new employer, and all the petitioner details are changed. (see the image). I want to know if I can change my petitioner information on the UStraveldocs portal without canceling the appointment and paying the fee again. Or what are other options for me?

I have submitted my DS-160. But I believe I can fill a new DS-160 and update its number in the US travel docs portal, and I don't need to cancel appointments or pay the fee again. Correct?

[image]

Comment: I don’t know the answer to your question, hence this Comment, not an Answer. The H1-B process is long and complicated, requiring major work by your proposed employer. Now, you propose to change significant aspects of your application: a different job, a different place, a different employer. An H1-B is only available when _a specific job has been found after survey and advertising to be not fillable by US workers_ . Your changes are not "details," but serious relevant major items. It seems extremely unlikely that a mere amendment will be allowed.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Thanks for your comment. Yes, a change of employer is a major amendment, and getting approval for it from USCIS is a different process that the new employer will do. USCIS conveys the decision via I-797 notice. However, my question is about the visa stamping process and the forms we need to fill out to get the Visa stamping appointment. Getting H1B status approval (employer does this) and getting H1B stamps (employee does this) are two different processes. -- COMMENT 1/2

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica
For the stamping, I will have to take the latest I-797 with me, but there is no issue in changing the employer multiple times prior to the first stamping or between two stampings, as long as all the employers do the amendment process well. -- COMMENT 2/2.

Comment: Our views differ. Please post an Answer to your own Question (that's OK here) when the issue has been decided.

Comment: You can just bring the new I797 to the interview and explain the situation

Comment: were you able to solve this problem? Did you end up cancelling the appointment to update the petitioner name or simply created a new DS160 for with the new petitioner information and went with the appointment? Also, is it a regular appointment or drop box?

Comment: Did this work ? just updating ds160 number and not cancelling the appointment ?

Comment: any update on this issue? I'm in the same situation. Mine is a Dropbox appointment